# Extend onclick function to javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, onclick

I'd like to include an onclick event in a JavaScript class, but since onclick is a function inside of the class the `this` variable won't work properly.

How can I modify/output the `this` variable from the onclick function?

```
img = new image();

function image() {
    this.width = 400;
    this.height = 600;
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function()
    {
        alert(this.width); // alerts undefined
    };
}
```

See JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZghRv/

Comment: Store the outer `this` in another variable: http://jsfiddle.net/ZghRv/2/

Comment: Would I need to use `that` for any subsequent references to `this`?

Comment: You only need that inside event handlers (inside them, `this` is what originated the event, e.g. the clicked element)

Comment: Just cache `this` to a variable and use it inside the handler. not a good idea to change the context inside the handler for a constant value define outside.

Comment: @PSL could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind() to create a new function that will have `this` set to the object you pass to bind().

```
img = new image();

function image() {
    this.width = 400;
    this.height = 600;
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = (function()
    {
        alert(this.width); // alerts undefined
    }).bind(this);  // <---  Add bind() here to pick the value of 'this' inside onclick
}
```

Check out [JavaScript Function bind](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind) for more info and interactive examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give reference to the outer `this`

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZghRv/3/